# File/Image upload in React Native 4 Web

Tags: reactjs, native, react-native-web

I have an issue while combining react with react-native using react-native-image-picker and i've no clue how to upload a image in react-native-web.

I have tried "react-native-everywhere-image-picker" but console showing that error in node-module react-native

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution to this?